# when will the frequency of a wireless signal change?

Tags: rf, wireless

So, one transmits a signal with particular wireless frequency. If a receiver and sender were not moving, what may cause the frequency of a wireless signal to change?

Comment: It isn't too clear exactly what you want to know here, could you clarify a bit? For example, the answer(s) could be "the temperature changes", "they are both using FM", "the batteries run down" or even "someone changed the tuning dial" ;-) Or are you referring to the Doppler effect? (what does moving have to do with it?) Or how the frequency is altered inside the units?

Answer (score 3):

**Frequency hopping**. In full "Frequency Hopping Spread Spectrum", or FHSS. It's a technique where transmitter and receiver continuously change the carrier frequency, at a rate of a couple of hundreds times per second.

Because the spectrum is spread FHSS is less susceptible to narrowband interference. Since only the transmitter and receiver know the frequency pattern it's also more difficult to intercept the communication. And FHSS (spread spectrum in general) causes less interference with other communications in the same band, so that more transmitter-receiver pairs can use the band simultaneously.